# How to set up and export illustrator file for a huge digital billboard?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, cmyk, rgb, jpeg

photos are much bigger than the pixels artboard and need the finale saved jpeg to be 1MB. When setting up illustrator file for a huge digital billboard what the best way to save and export the file?

Comment: Work at scale.. enlarge upon export.

Comment: A file of 1 MB for a billboard has no sense! Review and clarify your requirements.